# Windows Forms website resetting property value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have problem with my property values during handling events.
I have 2 buttons on windows form website, buttonA and buttonB. This is the code behind that I have:

```
public bool Clicked {get; set;}

public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clicked = false;
}

public void buttonA_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clicked = true;
}

public void buttonB_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Clicked)
    {
         // JS box pops out
    }
}
```

Something like this. WIth debugging, when I click on buttonA, Clicked sets on true, but when after it i Click on buttonB, it's false and this message box doesn't show. Why is this happening?

Comment: ASP.Net != WinForms.  And you can't call `MessageBox` on a server.

Comment: Are you using multi-threading?

Comment: Hmm, yea. Obviously I "lied" with code, just wanted to show that something is calling on if Clicked is true. I don't have this MessageBox and didn't think immediately that I actually can't call it :\

Comment: Here, I edited it, so you wouldn't get confused.

Comment: Lookup *page lifecycle* and you'll know what you need to know to get started with asp.net. page events are raised - and handled in a sequence. The client literally "speaks" with the server; server sends a page, client gets it, fills up a form and clicks a button. Client sends back the form to the server which will process the *postback* and serve a new page instance and its starts over. Your page code needs to know if the request is the initial one or if it's a postback from an existing *session*. This ain't *WinForms* my friend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net WebForms creates a separate instance of your page class for each server postback.
Any instance state is not preserved across HTTP requests.

To preserve state, you need to store it in ViewState or session state.

---

In addition, you cannot call UI methods like `MessageBox.Show` in server-side code.
You need to use Javascript.

Comment: Yea, that's what I didn't know. How to store it? @MessageBox.Show - I know for that, but in rush of giving example, I made bad example.

Comment: @Tommz: Use session state or view state, depending on what you want it associated with.